# Local extrema in one array

Tags: python, numpy

I have some data in Numpy in the form of a sine wave and I want to find the local maxima and minima of the function. I managed to create a loop to find the maxima and I could probably modify it to find the minima. The issue is, I want to create one array with all of the local extrema x-values and one with the corresponding y-values. All of the solutions to finding extrema in Numpy that I could find have the maxima and the minima in separate arrays and I want them together. I'd appreciate it if anyone could help.

Comment: After you have the arrays with extrema, you can just `np.concatenate` them together.

Comment: If this question is about how to turn `x = np.array(...)` and `y = np.array(...)` to a single 2D array, you can simple call `merged = np.stack([x, y], axis=1)`.

Comment: Maybe OP wants the resulting `x` and `y` arrays sorted by `x` (*after the merge*).

Comment: You can simply use `min(yourArray)` or `max(yourArray)` to find Y values. If you also want to find X that corresponds to Y: `yourArray.index(max(yourArray))` or for the minimum  `yourArray.index(min(yourArray))`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a 1d array such as

```
a = np.array( [1,2,1,2,3,2,4,5,1] )
```

you can find the local maximas

```
maximas = np.r_[True, a[1:] > a[:-1]] & np.r_[a[:-1] > a[1:], True]
# array([False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False])
```

and local minimas

```
minimas = np.r_[True, a[1:] < a[:-1]] & np.r_[a[:-1] < a[1:], True]
# array([ True, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True])
```

and combine them together

```
extremas = maximas + minimas
# array([ True, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True])
```

To get the values you can do

```
>>> a[ extremas ] 
array([1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 5, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution which uses scipy's [InterpolatedUnivariateSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.html) to create a spline which approximates your original sine function, which we can then get the derivative of and find the roots - these will be the x-locations of your local maxima and minima, which we then pass through the original function to get the corresponding y-locations:

```
from scipy import interpolate
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create sine wave
def f_curve(x):
    return np.sin(x)

# Get sine wave xs and ys
x = np.arange(0,2*np.pi,0.01)
y = f_curve(x)

# create spline function approximating original function
f = interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x, y, k=4)
xs = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 100)

# find roots of derivative function of spline (max and min occur when derivative=0)
# these are your x- and y-locations of the extrema
roots = f.derivative().roots()
root_ys = f_curve(roots)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(roots, root_ys, 'x', ms=12);
```

[image]

Comment: Note: only using the first derivative means that we'll pick up all maxima, minima and saddle points when applying this method to an arbitrary function, but in the case of the sine function we only have maxima and minima.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two more approaches to choose from-

1. Based on sign change of sinewave derivative
2. Using `scipy.signal.find_peaks`

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal

t = np.linspace(1e-4, 4, 1000)
s = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)

sdiff = np.diff(s, prepend=0)
# derivative of sine is cos and sin(90) = maxima and cos(90) = 0 ---> also the place where sign change occurs
mm = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(sdiff), append=np.sign(s[0])) != 0)

plt.plot(t, s, label='sine')
plt.plot(t, sdiff, label='cosine')
plt.scatter(t[mm], s[mm], label='numpy peaks', marker='*', c='r')

peaks, _ = signal.find_peaks(np.abs(s))
plt.scatter(t[peaks], s[peaks], label='scipy peaks', alpha=0.4)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Note: The figure depicts only part of the 4-periods of sinewave
[image]